# python cgi from Apache HTTP server gives script not found error

Tags: python, cgi, httpserver

I am trying to get into python cgi programming and installed Apache HTTP server on my Windows machine. I did the following changes to the httpd.conf file

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
```

and uncommented below line and added .py at the end

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

I placed the hello.py in htdocs folder. Here are the instructions I followed https://editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html

But the get this error

```
AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello.py
```

Comment: usually servers run code in folder `cgi/` or `cgi-bin/`

Comment: @furas Yes. I tried that too. I put my code in cgi-bin/ folder and made the following changes to httpd.conf ```<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>```.  
Same error.

Comment: apache should write errors in log file and maybe there will be more information. On Linux I would also try to set file executable and add shebang (`#!python`) in first line. BTW: For test I would use server built-in in Python - `python -m http.server --cgi`. But for real web page I would use Flask or Django instead of CGI.